# HKQuantity to Double - getting Active Energy Value from Healthkit

Tags: swift, healthkit

I'm working on a method that reads the active energy (kcal) from health kit but I have a problem getting the double value from the HKQuantity.
My code looks like this:

```
func getActiveEnergy () {
    let endDate = NSDate()
    let startDate = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(.Month, value: -1, toDate: endDate, options: [])

    let energySampleType = HKSampleType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierActiveEnergyBurned)
    let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamplesWithStartDate(startDate, endDate: endDate, options: .None)

    print ("start date: ", startDate)
    print ("end date: ", endDate)

    let query = HKSampleQuery(sampleType: energySampleType!, predicate: predicate, limit: 0, sortDescriptors: nil, resultsHandler: {
        (query, results, error) in
        if results == nil {
            print("There was an error running the query: \(error)")
        }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

            for activity in results as! [HKQuantitySample]
            {
                self.todayActiveEnergy = activity.quantity.doubleValueForUnit(HKUnit.countUnit())
                print(">>>>>", self.todayActiveEnergy)
            }

        }
    })
    self.healthKitStore.executeQuery(query)
}
```

My problem is with this row:

```
 self.todayActiveEnergy = activity.quantity.doubleValueForUnit(HKUnit.countUnit())
```

The `activity.quantity` returns indeed the right value (*156 kcal*) but when i try getting the double value from it (as done above) I get `libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException`

Any idea why this might happen?

Comment: If you want your energy value in kcal, why don't you use `HKUnit.kilocalorieUnit()`. I cannot test your code now, but HealthKit may be complaining that energy cannot be treated as count.

Comment: oh, I tried using HKUnit.kilocalorieUnit() and it works perfectly now. Thank you!

Comment: Would you please take some time to post an answer by yourself?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to OOPer for his comment. Changing the line to:

```
self.todayActiveEnergy = activity.quantity.doubleValueForUnit(HKUnit.kilocalorieUnit())
```

did the trick.